# Unable to Authorize an org in VS code getting below response in terminal

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

```
PS D:\LWCSession\LWC> sfdx force:auth:web:login
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=aee1a7bf19e7^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=AFdNI-DWiP7RrZdfNgWFWxe3pnXuqpAFkU4CcjXiMDA' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=aee1a7bf19e7^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=AFdNI-DWiP7RrZdfNgWFWxe3pnXuqpAFkU4CcjXiMDA' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=aee1a7bf19e7^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=AFdNI-DWiP7RrZdfNgWFWxe3pnXuqpAFkU4CcjXiMDA' ] }
{ Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs:
   [ '/c',
     'start',
     '""',
     '/b',
     'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code^&client_id=PlatformCLI^&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1717%2FOauthRedirect^&state=aee1a7bf19e7^&prompt=login^&scope=refresh_token%20api%20web^&code_challenge=AFdNI-DWiP7RrZdfNgWFWxe3pnXuqpAFkU4CcjXiMDA' ] }
```

Comment: Do you have node.js installed on your PC? If not then install it and try again. Otherwise upgrade npm and sfdx with respective commands `npm update` and `sfdx update`, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

The ENOENT error code is the operating system telling you it can't find npm.

If you don't have npm or js installed try to installed them first if you already have or or if the problem persists after you install then you probably either need to configure your PATH environment variable or use an absolute path for npm